# Find element with given text using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a table like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsa3bfj9/). I need to find data related to the row which contains given text.

[image: table]

For example, by providing `1707`, I need to get all data in table row which contains `1707`. So output should be as below.

> Tuesday   2014-08-05  1707    33  43  47  52  image   text

Currently I'm accessing data on html page as below.

```
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup
                .connect("url here").timeout(300000).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

        Element table = doc.select("table#customers").first();          
        if (table != null) {
            Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td").iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("Day : " + iterator.next().text());
                System.out.println("Date : " + iterator.next().text());                 
                System.out.println("Draw : " + iterator.next().text());                 
                System.out.println("No1 : " + iterator.next().text());
                System.out.println("No2 : " + iterator.next().text());
                System.out.println("No3 : " + iterator.next().text());
                System.out.println("No4 : " + iterator.next().text());
                System.out.println("Symbol : " + iterator.next().text());
                System.out.println("Non : " + iterator.next().text());
            }
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("No results were found according to search criteria.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code return all data on table. But I need to get data related to given text.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown in [jsoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) you can use the pseudo-selector `:contains(text)`:

```
table.select("tr:contains(1707) td")
```

*You can try it [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~-mWnOycDWhCAof7USavfp01FYFs)*